# Failure to open standard applications

Tags: unity, icons, evolution

I was just getting comfortable with Ubuntu then....

Tried installing Geary to test it
It crashed on opening and has never worked

Tried installing evolution to test it
It crashed on opening and has never worked

Tried to open System Settings from top right icon to see if there was a reinstall item for Ubuntu 16/04
It no longer works at all

Now, whether the first failure set up the later failures or not I cannot say but some applications (not all) fail to open.

Thunderbird, Firefox, LibreOffice, Calculator all ok.

Used the top left icon to search for system settings but it provides a completely unfamiliar window with icons in black on white and very different from the expected feature.

Is there a last-ditch reinstall option to resolve these issues. If not, I shall have to revert to Windows as this is all wasting too much time.

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Sorry - just to add, I have tried removal and reinstallation of those offending apps without success.

Comment: How did you installed those softwares? Have you had any error log you could post here ?

Comment: Did you interrupt `apt` and/or `dpkg` while they were working? Sounds like you have broken packages.

Comment: Thanks for such prompt replies to my first ever post! Each application was installed using the 'Ubuntu Software' library utility. However, having already installed Synaptic I have also tried to install/uninstall a couple of times using that.  I will admit to not having kept a good account of my actions - it took me some time to realise that there was a problem.  I shall try again and post any error log I can find.

Answer (score 0):

try looking for broken packages using synaptic package manager. It can be found at 'Custom Filters'.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Comment: Thank you. I checked for broken packages without success. However, I did see the category marked 'Missing Recommended Packages' and installed likely candidates.

Comment: what happened after you installed those packages?

Comment: Sorry, forum timed out on me!    Thank you.     I checked for broken packages without success. However, I did see the category marked 'Missing Recommended Packages' and installed likely candidates.  This resulted in the restoration of functionality of the System Settings menu. I have reinstalled Evolution using the 'Ubuntu Software' utility. All seems well when I click the launcher button but after a delay the application appears to shut down with no message.

Comment: I used command line to remove, autoremove and install Evolution.    The resulting error messages are given below       (evolution:22494): e-data-server-WARNING **: build_categories_filename: Failed to rename '/home/alan/.evolution/categories.xml' to '/home/alan/.local/share/evolution/categories.xml': No such file or directory

(evolution:22494): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.evolution.shell' is not installed               I have no idea how to add new lines in these postings. Very new to this so sorry.